# Git doesn't respect GIT_PAGER value set in ~/.emacs_bash in emacs shell until manually exported

Tags: git, bash, shell, emacs

If I open a new shell (`M-x shell`), the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable is set, but git still tries to use the default until I manually set `GIT_PAGER`.

Content of `~/.emacs_bash`:

```
GIT_PAGER=cat
```

New shell:

```
[~/myrepo]$ echo $GIT_PAGER
cat
[~/myrepo]$ git grep foobar
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
myfile.txt:foobar
[~/myrepo]$ export GIT_PAGER=$GIT_PAGER
[~/myrepo]$ git grep foobar
myfile.txt:foobar
[~/myrepo]$
```

Why is this and how might I get git to recognize `GIT_PAGER` from the outset of opening a new shell buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `~/.emacs_bash`, try

```
export GIT_PAGER=cat
```

instead of just `GIT_PAGER=cat`.  It needs to be exported for child processes (like git) to see it.  When you reassigned it, it worked because you exported it then.

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized that.